# Showing that an infinite series converges at a certain values of n

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus

How could I go about showing that:
$$1.4\le\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^2\le2$$
for all $n\ge4$? I feel like turning the sum into an integral by taking a limit of the sum would be helpful but I'm not sure how to do so in this case due to n starting at 4. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n$ the given sum so since it's increasing sequence then
$$S_n\ge S_4=1+\frac14+\frac19+\frac1{25}>1.4$$
and

$$S_n\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty1/k^2\le1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k(k-1)}\le1+\underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k}_{\text{telecopic sum}=1}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$\frac{1}{k^2}=\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^3}\right)-\frac{1}{6k^3(k+1)^3}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{5}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{6(n+1)^3}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^3(k+1)^3}\right)$$
hence, for any $n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}<\frac{5}{3}$$
and for any $n\geq 4$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\geq H_{4}^{(2)}=\frac{205}{144}>1.4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$.

Notice that $S_n$ is increasing on $n$, thus for the lower bound it suffices to see that $S_4 = 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 \geq 1.4$.

For the upper bound, an integral test can also help, since
$$S_n \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 1 + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = 2.$$